# return object via array values

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object and would like to find and return the object values based on an array.

```
var profile = {
   'firstName' : 'John',
   'lastName' : 'Doe',
   'mood' : 'happy'
};

var updated= ['firstName','mood'];
```

The updated array gets changed with the key when a the relevant field has been changed.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you need underscore.js for that? simple for loop will do the trick.

Comment: What do you mean with "`The updated array gets changed with the key when a the relevant field has been changed.`"? You should also add an expected output (format).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have an object and would like to find and return the object values based on an array.

You don't need underscore.js for this. You can do this with plain js simply by iterating over the array and extracting the necessary properties from your object:

```js
var profile = {
  'firstName': 'John',
  'lastName': 'Doe',
  'mood': 'happy'
};

var updated = ['firstName', 'mood'];

updated.forEach(function(prop) {
  console.log(profile[prop]);
});
```

> The updated array gets changed with the key when a the relevant field has been changed.

Not sure I understand you exactly, but it seems that you want an array of values for properties of the `profile` object whose names are contained in the `updated` array. Using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) would do the trick:

```js
var profile = {
  'firstName': 'John',
  'lastName': 'Doe',
  'mood': 'happy'
};

var updated = ['firstName', 'mood'];

var values = updated.map(function(prop) {
  return profile[prop];
});

console.log(values);
```

Comment: talk about over kill.... thanks man. Was so caught up with the issue forgot the basics. Thanks again :)

Comment: @mattts no worries amigo, glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Seeing that you asked for an underscore solution, here's one:

[**Pick**](http://underscorejs.org/#pick) returns an object with just the keys that you want:

```
var result = _.pick(profile, updated);
```

So result will look like:

```
{
   'firstName' : 'John',
   'mood' : 'happy'
}
```

If you need just the values in an array then use the [**values**](http://underscorejs.org/#values) function:

```
var values = _.values(result);
```